# SVN "no spcae left on device"

Tags: svn, commit

I've recently faced a problem - I tried to commit some files today on svn and all the time, after "adding" all the files(they are marked as "added" after that) by the end of commit I get an error:

> Commit failed(details follow):
>   Can't write to file '/srv/svn/labs/tp/db/txn-protorevs/3187-2qk.rev': No space left on device

And of course the files are not commited to repository. I can delete the files that are already there, but I can't commit new ones.
Is there anything I can do to cope with that, or is that an issue with server and I should conntact my teacher?

Answer (score 1):

Seems it is because of the iNode issue, even your disk still has the space

http://blog.thilinamb.com/2010/03/svn-error-no-space-left-on-device.html

Answer (score 0):

Log into the server. Delete any stuff on that device you do not need.

Otherwise just buy more disk space.

Besides why not just read the error message.

But SVN is not that efficient in version control.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. As I was using Eclipse on Windows and SVN runs on Windows too, it was not obvious (to me) that the problem was on the server side. 
BTW the server had a bug that filled the disk to 100%.